# Optimization of filtering in Python

Tags: python

I need to run a complex function, `can_clump`, on many objects in python. This takes quite a long time to run so I am trying to optimize.

Only some of the objects need to have `can_clump` run on them so I am trying to filter.

The solution that I currently have is here:

```py
for clump1 in stored.clumps:
    for clump2 in stored.clumps:
        if clump1.classification = clump2.classification:
            if clump1.can_clump(clump2):
                #some code here
```

But I am unsure if I can combine the if statements if an and to simplify it or if that will require the python to python to check both:

```py
for clump1 in stored.clumps:
    for clump2 in stored.clumps:
        if clump1.classification = clump2.classification and clump1.can_clump(clump2):
            #some code here
```

Alternatively, it might even be faster to just filter the list before iteration:

```py
for clump1 in stored.clumps:
    for clump2 in filter(lambda x: x.classification == clump1.classification, stored.clumps):
         if clump1.can_clump(clump2):
              #some code here
```

I am unsure as to which one is faster and should be implemented.

Comment: You're repeatedly using `=` when you mean `==`.

Comment: The indentation of your code is also messed-up.

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python compound if condition", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.  As for the timing issue, the way to find out is to code up each of the three and time them on a smaller, representative data set.

Comment: I am unable to create a smaller data set because I am using proteins files to test it which I cannot create so I have to make premade ones from PDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, combining your two conditions is easy:

```
for clump1 in stored.clumps:
    for clump2 in stored.clumps:
        if clump1.classification == clump2.classification and clump1.can_clump(clump2):
            #some code here
```

does what you want, and it short-circuits; if the first test fails, `can_clump` won't be called.

Secondly, as a rule, `filter` is slower when it requires a `lambda` to implement it; the only time you see meaningful savings is when the predicate is itself a built-in implemented in C. If you already need to call an existing, Python defined function, then `filter` is generally no better or worse, so there is little harm in using it.

So for your case, assuming the `classification` is a built-in type (or a C extension implemented type) you *might* be able to optimize a bit with:

```
for clump1 in stored.clumps:
    for clump2 in filter(clump1.can_clump, filter(clump1.classification.__eq__, stored.clumps)):
          #some code here
```

That said, this is all micro-optimization. Even if it works, we're talking about *maybe* a 10% speedup, if this is the hottest part of your code, and everything goes just right. As a rule, worrying about micro-optimizations is a waste of time; 99% of the time, the performance is fine without it *or* the performance is unacceptably slow whether or not you do it.

In this case, you'll likely get a lot more out of pre-grouping your clumps, reducing the `O(n²)` work of nested iteration of `stored.clumps` with something that can do at least some of the work in `O(n log n)` (with `sorted`+`itertools.groupby`) or `O(n)` (with a multi-`dict`, e.g. `collections.defaultdict(list)`). For example, a preprocessing run to group by classification could be:

```
# Imports at top of file
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import product

# Code using them
clumps_by_classification = defaultdict(list)

for clump in stored.clumps:
    clumps_by_classification[clump.classification].append(clump)
```

Now instead of comparing *every* clump to every other clump, you can compare the subgroups with matching classifications:

```
for classification, clumps in clumps_by_classification.items():
    for clump1, clump2 in product(clumps, repeat=2):
        if clump1.can_clump(clump2):
            # some code here
```

Depending on whether clump ordering should matter, and whether clumps should be able to clump with themselves, you might save more by replacing `product` with another `itertools` function like `combinations`, `combinations_with_replacement`, or `permutations`.

Yes, in theory, that `product(repeat=2)` step keeps the work `O(n²)`, but now it's `O(n²)` when `n` is the largest subgroup with the same `classification`, not in terms of the whole set of clumps.